# how can use sender and tags together in c#?

Tags: c#

I want develop a calculator by using c#, and I do not use method click for all button from 0 to 9 I want I have just one method and if I click the each button wrote in textbox by using sender and tags.
best regards

```
enter code here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Final
{
public partial class Form1 : Form

{
bool names;
int counter;
string name;
double ans, num;
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Environment.Exit(0);
}
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
textBox1.Text += "1";
counter++;
again();
}
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
textBox1.Text += "2";
counter++;
again();
}

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
textBox1.Text += "3";
counter++;
again();
}
```

Comment: I write method for all buttons when clicked textbox write this but I want just have one method and I named the tag in properties for all buttons

Comment: then add your code to the question

Comment: remove code from comment it's place is in the question

Comment: sorry for this ,also all codes are same

Answer (score 2):

You can have just one handler for all digit buttons, and then you can extract its value like this:

```
int num = int.Parse(((Button)sender).Text);
```

This assumes that you set the `Text` property of the buttons to: 0,1,2..9

You can access the `Tag` property just like the `Text`:

```
var txt = ((Button)sender).Tag).ToString();
textBox1.Text += txt;
```

Comment: thanks ,how can call the tags ?because I wrote there the name of buttons

Comment: See the amended answer

Answer (score 1):

Set `.Tag` to correspondent value and then retrieve it from sender by casting it to `Button` type.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    textBox1.Text += button.Tag.ToString();
    counter++;
    again();
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    button1.Tag = 1;
    button1.Click += button_Click;

    button2.Tag = 2;
    button2.Click += button_Click;

    // and so on for other buttons
}
```

Comment: thanks :) ,Wrote for each button or write just this for all?

Comment: Use one `button_Click` method as `Click` eventhandler for all buttons